# How can I get Vim to ignore all user configuration, as if it were freshly installed?

Tags: startup

In order to ensure that behaviour is not affected by my personal config, I want to start Vim in a way that ignores *all* my user-installed config files, as if Vim had just been freshly installed for the first time and the user had run it immediately.

This is addressed [in the FAQ](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5) which suggests that the answer is to start Vim with the following command:

```
vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE
```

This gets *most* of the way there, but the `runtimepath` option still contains `~/.vim` and, notably, `~/.vim/after`, (so e.g. if I subsequently turn on file type detection and change filetype, code in `~/.vim/after/syntax/the_relevant_filetype.vim` will be executed).

I can workaround this specific problem by invoking the following commands on startup*:

```
:set runtimepath-=~/.vim
:set runtimepath-=~/.vim/after
```

...but I'm not sure if:

1. This is a robust solution: Are those the only paths that can cause user-configuration to take effect? Is there anything else I haven't thought of?
2. There is a better way of achieving the desired result.

<sub>* By using `--cmd` or `-u vimrc` shell arguments, or simply by typing them manually.</sub>

**EDIT**: Here's one specific example of the sort of problem I'm trying to fix. (Although I'd like the solution to fix any other possible issues I might not yet have encounted.):

1. Create a file ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim, containing the content:

   ```
   noremap i :echom "This is not default behaviour"<CR>
   ```

   Now we have some user-installed configuration that we want to ignore. Let's test the solution suggested by the FAQ.
2. Run Vim with the command:

   ```
   vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE
   ```
3. Enter the commands:

   ```
   :filetype plugin on
   :set ft=c
   i
   ```

**Desired behaviour**: Vim should enter Insert mode. This is what it would do if no user configuration existed.

**Observed behaviour**: Vim prints out "This is not default behaviour"

Comment: On a Unix-like system, what if you do: `HOME=/dev/null vim -u NONE`?

Comment: @muru Nice idea, and probably worth adding as an answer, but it's not *perfect*. You obviously lose the ability to e.g. `:cd ~`, but also the default location of the `viminfo` file is in $HOME, which can cause E138. I guess creating a new, empty directory and using that for $HOME might be the best solution.

Comment: @muru Just occurred to me that if you're setting $HOME, then presumably you don't also need to specify `-u NONE`?

Comment: in which case `/tmp` might be better, it was my first thought, but then I chose /dev/null as a black hole. ... Or something like `HOME=$(mktemp -d) vim ...`.

Comment: Won't it read system vimrc if you don't use `-u NONE`? Depends on what behaviour you need, I suppose.

Comment: @muru I thought I wanted it to read anything that came with the installation, but nothing that has been added afterwards, but on reflection maybe I do just want `-u NONE`. Thanks for the suggestions! (And again, you should probably add them as an answer.)

Comment: What are you trying to do? [(XY Problem)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/188334)

Comment: @mMontu ensure that none of the behaviour I'm seeing is caused by user config.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

As of Vim [8.0.1554](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/072687032683b1994d25a114893d9a6f8bc36612), you can use **`vim --clean`** (or **`nvim --clean`** for Neovim). This method is recommended by [`:help bugs`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#bugs).

[`:help --clean`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#--clean) docs:

> Similar to "-u DEFAULTS -U NONE -i NONE":
> - initializations from files and environment variables is
> skipped
> - **'runtimepath' and 'packpath' are set to exclude home
> directory entries** (does not happen with -u DEFAULTS).
> - the |defaults.vim| script is loaded, which implies
> 'nocompatible': use Vim defaults
> - no |gvimrc| script is loaded
> - no viminfo file is read or written

Comment: Nice! This is a lot simpler than messing around with the `$HOME` variable. Goodjob Vim developers. And thanks to you for the answer!

Comment: `--clean` also works with `neovim` on master now (https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/aa82f8b88fe82077740894dd387801384e0558b6, to be included in 0.4.0), but does not exclude the home directory.

Comment: (yet, that patch is waiting to be ported)

Answer (score 15):

One way to eliminate user-specific files would be to use a different value of `$HOME`. To allow nothing to be read, or written to (such as viminfo), you could use `/dev/null`:

```
HOME=/dev/null vim -u NONE
```

This will cause errors about `viminfo`, so, instead you could create a temporary folder, or use an existing one (like `/tmp`):

```
HOME=$(mktemp -d) vim -u NONE
```

With such a `$HOME`, `-u NONE` may not be needed, depending on what your administrator has added to the system-wide `vimrc`. For example, on all lab systems I administer, I added a `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` (sourced by the packaged Vim's default `/etc/vim/vimrc`) that has `nocompatible`, `syntax`, etc., set, and `filetype on` as well.

Comment: vim -i NONE to prevent loading viminfo

Comment: Just for posterity's sake, I'd like to point out that this was my accepted answer until the `--clean` option was added to Vim.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer much of that but one point that I don't see mentioned, and re answering an interpretation of what is in the title

> How can I get Vim to ignore all user configuration, as if it were
>   freshly installed?

some have suggested `vim -u NONE`  or `vim -u NORC`

that's in some ways a bit more barebones than just no vimrc file. When I type 'i', it doesn't say 'insert'.  You may want it to still say 'insert'.  If you started vim with your vimrc file blank then it would show insert

that's because vim loads a default config first.

You can point vim to that default file to get the effect of your vimrc file being blank. Check that you have `/etc/vim/vimrc`,  and you can do `vim -u /etc/vim/vimrc`   or on osx, the default file is `/usr/share/vim/vicmrc`

Comment: I think that's exactly what vim --clean will do for you.

Comment: @quemeraisc `vim --clean` will load `defaults.vim`. This answer is referring to the system vimrc (See `:help system-vimrc`.), which I think is *not* loaded by `vim --clean`.

Comment: @barlap: To avoid confusion with defaults.vim (see `:help defaults.vim`), might be better to change the wording `default config` to `system vimrc` in this answer. Or even better, discuss both in the answer!

Answer (score 0):

From [Vim-FAQ  2.5](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5):

> 2.5. I have a "xyz" (some) problem with Vim. How do I determine it is a
>        problem with my setup or with Vim?  / Have I found a bug in Vim?
>
> First, you need to find out, whether the error is in the actual
>   runtime files or any plugin that is distributed with Vim or whether it
>   is a simple side effect of any configuration option from your .vimrc
>   or .gvimrc. So first, start vim like this:
>
> ```
> vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE
> ```
>
> this starts Vim in nocompatible mode (-N), without reading your
>   viminfo file (-i NONE), without reading any configuration file (-u
>   NONE for not reading .vimrc file and -U NONE for not reading a .gvimrc
>   file) or even plugin.

Comment: Despite being in the FAQ, this doesn't actually work, for the reasons mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Rich From your comment on the question: `ensure that none of the behaviour I'm seeing is caused by user config` -- then it looks like you are trying to do *exactly* what is being explained in this FAQ. I've re-read your question and still don't understand what are the reasons you mentioned.

Comment: I am indeed trying to do exactly what is being explained in the FAQ. But the solution it gives doesn't work, because of the `runtimepath` setting.

Comment: What exactly is wrong about the `runtimepath`? It seems like the default for this option, as explained in `:help rtp`. How is this value affecting your test?

Comment: @Rich I mean, do you see any differences when comparing to a fresh install after you turn on filetype detection?

Comment: @Rich, this is the documented way to start Vim like in a fresh install. Also the 'rtp' setting is like this in a fresh install. Perhaps you are looking for the '--no-plugins' switch or 'loadplugins' setting

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt The `rtp` setting isn't incorrect. But it points to user configuration files. The documentation is incorrect to state that starting the Vim in this way causes it to work like a fresh install, as I (attempted, but obviously failed to) explain in the original question.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I might be reading the documentation incorrectly, but I think --noplugin affects code in `plugin` but not code in `after`. I'll test and get back to you if I'm wrong.

Comment: I've updated the question. Hopefully that clarifies the problem!

Comment: How is this different from a scratch install, where you put that file into your ~/.vim directory?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Sorry, I don't understand. How is what different from a scratch install? Where I put which file into my ~/.vim directory?