# MacOS Terminal CPU spike after exiting Vim

Tags: terminal, macos, performance

I'm using Vim 8.1 from homebrew on MacOs 10.14.6. Whenever I exit vim back to the terminal, the first keypress in the terminal afterward results in a beachball and CPU spike to 100%, with terminal listed as "not responding" in Activity Monitor. The spike lasts for 5 to 25 seconds, then the terminal is fine until the next time I exit vim. vim is the only thing that seems to be causing this, so far. This behavior is recent -- this same configuration had been working fine before -- although I have updated vim from homebrew in an attempt to fix the problem.

I'm wondering if there's a network issue somewhere (I'm behind a corporate firewall where the admins change the rules occasionally), or some other interaction betweeen vim and terminal that I'm not accounting for.

Comment: Why would there be networking between vim and the terminal? Have you tried using any of the profile/debug options to get a look at where the time spike is happening? How are you running/using/quitting vim in this process? Data is the key to solving any performance mystery.

Comment: At a guess: if you have 100s of files open, vim might be dealing with cleaning up swap files... but again, *this is a guess*. We need more data

Comment: I'm on the command line, in a bash shell. I type `vim ...file...`, and when I exit vim the terminal beachballs as soon as I type anything on the keyboard. This does not happen for anything else I run from the terminal. I suspect network because that's what could have changed recently since it's beyond my control. `vim` is the binary installed by homebrew. I may still blame bash for the problem, but the odd thing is it only affects vim.

Comment: Again: profile/log—realtime data is necessary here. Is it 100s of files, or a single file? Vim doesnt network unless you use netrw to edit files over a network, or you touch something on an NFS (and then its the filesystem networking, not vim).

Comment: does this still happen if you disable your vimrc? `vim --clean` ([others](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6112/how-can-i-get-vim-to-ignore-all-user-configuration-as-if-it-were-freshly-instal))?

Comment: If you quit Vim but _don't_ press a key for, say, one minute, then does the terminal hang the first time you press a key, or does the problem only occur if you start typing soon after quitting Vim?

Comment: What is the terminal displaying before and during the hang? If you run Vim with the command `vim && echo hi` does the `hi` display immediately after quitting Vim, or does that also cause the hang?

Comment: If you open another terminal and execute the command `ps | grep [Vv]im` in it while the hang is in progress, what is the output?

Comment: Behavior remains with `vim --clean`.

Comment: `vim && echo hi` prints the `hi` and then beachballs -- so that points to a non-vim issue, I would think.

Comment: Behavior seems to affect only a single terminal window at a time -- if I open another terminal, the other doesn't have the same problem.

Comment: I don't know what's causing your issue, but I get a similar kind of problem when I execute vim from a `bash` script which I have sourced. On the way out of the sourced script, the script does: `eval "unset my_var; (exit $my_var)"` and it's this part which hangs inexplicably. I've noticed it especially with vim, but possibly it's occurring with other commands in similar situations. When I changed `(exit...)` to `return $my_var` it seems to have made the problem go away. That shouldn't have made a noticeable difference, but it apparently did. Running bash `3.2.57(1)` and vim `8.1 patch 1-2400`.

Comment: I have TabNine installed (https://tabnine.com), and I think something with its process was causing the problems. Odd that a reboot didn't fix it, unless it wasn't finding a network server it needed.

Comment: It seems that I just started having the same issue, but I don't have TabNine installed. Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: I haven't noticed a problem lately, although I've since upgraded laptop and macOS. I'm still running TabNine.

Comment: I have a similar problem after Mac upgrade to Big Sur, any solution to this?